# on 64bit system, how to pass in int as void *

Tags: c, 64-bit, system, porting

There is a `process_create()` function, which has a param as `void*`.
If I want to pass in an `int`, how could I do that to avoid build error from compiler?
I can't change the param list to `process_create()`

Comment: What platforms do you use? What compiler (compilers)?

Comment: You could use that pointer to pass, well, a *pointer* to the integer. Of course that introduces issues about address spaces and knowing when the child process has finished with that memory, but there must be some way of handling that or why does that function accept a pointer parameter?

Answer (score 4):

To be safe, you can cast your integer to `intptr_t`, which is guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer, and back.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

inline void *int_to_ptr(int n) {
    return (void *) (intptr_t) n;
}

inline int ptr_to_int(void *p) {
    return (int) (intptr_t) p;
}
```

Use `int_to_ptr` when calling `process_create`, and `ptr_to_int` when converting back.

This is still technically not portable ISO C, because:

1. While it is guaranteed that an arbitrary pointer will survive a roundtrip to `intptr_t` and back, it is undefined behavior to even create a pointer from an `intptr_t` value like does not correspond to a valid pointer, such as 1. In theory, the implementation might choke on the invalid pointer, or the integer value might not survive the roundtrip from `intptr_t` to pointer and back.
2. In theory, some C implementation could have `int` wider than pointers, in which case some valid integer values will overflow in the case to `intptr_t`.

Both of these cases are highly unlikely to be encountered in practice. C code in widely deployed and portable software uses casts like the above for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for this response. This works very well on the wide range of CPU I needed to support calling this type of API. I was using C++ but your answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could just cast the `int` to `void*`, but that's not portable. For example, it's conceivable, albeit somewhat unlikely, that `sizeof(int)>sizeof(void*)`. So, if you want to be portable you should pass a pointer to an `int`.

For example you could allocate storage for `int` with `malloc`.

```
int *myparam = malloc(sizeof(*myparam));
*myparam = 42;
process_create(myparam);
```

Without knowing more about what `process_create` is and does, I can't say who should be responsible for calling `free` on that block of memory.

My assumption here is that `process_create` is asynchronous and that the pointer could be read some time after the call to `process_create` returns. However, if the pointer will be read during the execution of `process_create` then you can make it even simpler.

```
int myparam = 42;
process_create(&myparam);
```

So, the bottom line is that I think it best to pass an `int*` to `process_create`. Exactly how you achieve that depends on the operation of `process_create`.

Comment: That's complicated.Could I do the following transform (void *)(uintptr_t) uintptr_t is a platform type, it's uint64_t on 64 bit system, and uint32_t on 32 bit system

Comment: Well you could, but I don't see how it relates to the question. The question talks about `int`.